# Regex + python27: How to get characters not matching regexes?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have the following regexes:

```
import re
identifiers = "[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*"
address = "\\$" + identifiers + "(\\." + identifiers + ")"*
s = re.findall(pattern, "hello\nworld\n$myworld\nrandom!!(+")
```

As a result I get:

```
[('hello', ''), ('', ''), ('world', ''), ('', ''), ('$myworld', ''), ('', ''), ('random', ''), ('', ''), ('', ''), ('', ''), ('', ''), ('', '')]
```

How can I write a regex which matches not an identifier or an address? Assuming that I can string more and more regexes together in pattern, i.e:

pattern = address | identifier | string | comment | ...

How can I say ~pattern? By doing that I can give a message saying that the following characters are not understood: "!!(+" (ignoring whitespace)

Comment: I have provided the string "hello\nworld\n$myworld\nrandom!!(+" as an example whereby the !!(+ would be identified as not being recognized. But I would also like the solution to be scalable so that adding regexes to pattern would not be a problem.

Comment: What does *the !!(+ would be identified as not being recognized* mean? Do you wan to exclude any "identifier" that has `!!(+` symbols in it? I am asking because [your current regex does not match those entities](https://regex101.com/r/xK2cE7/2).

Comment: I want to "recognize" them as not being part of the predefined patterns (pattern = address | identifier). i.e. I want to detect that those symbols are excluded.

Comment: Im not sure, but maybe you need "negative lookahead assertion" ? http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: It looks like what you're doing is writing a parser, and for a parser of any complexity, regular expressions are really the wrong approach. I would actually recommend looking into libraries that are designed to help you write parsers, such as [pyparsing](https://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/).

Comment: Agreed with @rmunn. You're writing at minimum a context free grammar, and regular expressions *cannot* recognize a grammar. This is a *mathematical* limitation. You're outside of your knowledge base here. In the long term, you should learn the basics of about how compilers work and are written; the techniques apply to a broad range of text processing problems. If you need something in the short term, pyparsing as rmunn recommends is a good way to go. You'll define each valid token in your grammar using a regex, and then you'll define how the tokens fit together to make a grammar.

Comment: Agreed that a library would make things much more easier for me, i.e. antlr but I am not parsing, I am lexing where regular expressions are adequate for that which is what you are describing. However the problem is without using such a library, stringing the regexes together do not have an explicit priority. It seems that the longest regex matches which is fine however if I use '.' the dot to catch out regexes which I dont want it matches everything. I was wondering if there was a pattern which could match the "rest" or somethign to imply the order

Comment: If you're just trying to say you want to throw an error when you find characters that can't be part of a legal token, then why not break the regular expressions down into a state machine? Regular expressions can only categorize a full string as matching or not matching. (Group capturing might go a little further, but I don't think that's helpful for lexing where you want to stop consuming characters so they can be used for the next token.) Unless I'm mistaken, this is usually how lexers work: a character at a time. This allows you to dynamically figure out what token you're parsing as you go.

Comment: Realistically, a set of simple regular expressions isn't enough for lexing. You have multiple regular expressions, and these (each one a small, deterministic finite state machine) combine into a full state machine with multiple end states (each lexeme is a distinct end state). The problem is that if you combine the state machines for of all the regexes in the raw, you get a *nondeterministic* state machine, which you then need to convert into a more complicated but deterministic one to be able to lex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure it will satisfy your needs, but you can get the other characters by replacing valid patterns with nothing.

```
>>> import re
>>> identifiers = "[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*"
>>> invalid = re.sub(identifiers, "", "hello\nworld\n$myworld\nrandom!!(+")
>>> print invalid
'\n\n$\n!!(+'
```

Comment: I think it is a practical way to achieve this as it seems that there is no regex for this sort of thing without having to manually take into account all the patterns and carefully crafting a not pattern. Ill keep the post open for a bit longer in case there are other answers out there.

Answer (score 0):

I made an small change in identifier pattern which might solve your expectation, I guess

```
identifiers = "[^a-zA-Z][^a-zA-Z0-9]*"
invalid = re.findall(identifiers, "hello\nworld\n$myworld\nrandom!!(+")
invalid = "".join(invalid)
```

output
Invalid: '\n\n$\n!!(+'